# Create subdocument and save value with Angularjs and Mongoose (meanjs)

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, mongoose, mean, meanjs

I am trying to add a value to the 'twitter' key that is a subdocument 'social' with: **this.social.twitter** in the controller. Using that breaks form submission, no errors in console. If I comment that out and submit the form, it submits and adds social with twitter and facebook to the mongodb with empty strings.

When the form submits, it does add the values for name and image.

**My schema:**

```
var McSchema = new Schema({
name: {
    type: String,
    default: '',
    required: 'A name is required',
    trim: true
},
image: {
    type: String,
    default: '',
    required: 'An image is required',
    trim: true
},
social: {
    twitter: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        trim: true
    },
    facebook: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        trim: true
    }
},
created: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
},
user: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
}
```

});

**My controller:**

```
angular.module('mcs').controller('McsController', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$location', 'Authentication', 'Mcs',
function($scope, $stateParams, $location, Authentication, Mcs) {
    $scope.authentication = Authentication;

    // Create new MC
    $scope.create = function() {
        // Create new Mc object
        var mc = new Mcs ({
            name: this.name,
            image: this.image,
            twitter: this.social.twitter
        });

        // Redirect after save
        mc.$save(function(response) {
            $location.path('mcs/' + response._id);

            // Clear form fields
            $scope.name = '';
            $scope.image = '';
            $scope.twitter = '';
        }, function(errorResponse) {
            $scope.error = errorResponse.data.message;
        });
    };

    ...
```

]);

**My form:**

```
<section data-ng-controller="McsController">
<div class="page-header">
    <h1>New Mc</h1>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12">
    <form class="form-horizontal" data-ng-submit="create()" novalidate>
        <fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="name">Name</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" data-ng-model="name" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="image">Image</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" data-ng-model="image" id="image" class="form-control" placeholder="image" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="social-twitter">Twitter</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" data-ng-model="mc.twitter" id="social-twitter" class="form-control" placeholder="@">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
            </div>
            <div data-ng-show="error" class="text-danger">
                <strong data-ng-bind="error"></strong>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: shouldn't new Mcs have a social with an object instead of a twitter.  something like `social: {twitter:this.social.twitter}`

Answer (score 0):

You have `data-ng-model="mc.twitter"` set in your html but in the javascript you attempt to access `this.social.twitter`. If I haven't missed anything, that's you problem. You should change either one of them to have them be the same, for instance changing your html to: `data-ng-model="social.twitter"`.

Comment: Thanks Materik, I am also accessing name/image with: this.name and this.image and then accessing them from the form with mc.name and mc.image respectively and those work. When I introduce this.social.twitter is when the issue arises. The problem persists whether I try mc.social.twitter, social.twitter or mc.twitter. It seems that mc.twitter is right, but this.social.twitter is wrong.

Comment: I don't understand where mc comes from. Instead of using this, couldn't you use $scope.mc.twitter? That should work.

Comment: I was not able to get it to work. mc comes from:

var mc = new Mcs ({
    name: this.name,
    image: this.image,
    twitter: this.social.twitter
});

Both name and image work fine, only social.twitter does not. The only difference is that it is a subdocument.

Comment: Have you tried to use @scope.social.twitter instead of this.social.twitter, given that it says data-ng-model="social.twitter" in your html.

Comment: The html is using: `data-ng-model="mc.twitter"`, not `data-ng-model="social.twitter"`. I just tried `@scope.social.twitter` instead of `this.social.twitter`, still unable to submit form.

Comment: try this: change data-ng-model to "social.twitter". then change this.social.twitter to $scope.social.twitter (I accidentally typed @, my bad, it should be $). this should definitely work.